# Declare and initialize constant in header file

Tags: c++, objective-c, constants, header-files, compile-time-constant

I'm well versed in the typical paradigm of:

```
//.h
extern const int myInt;

//.c, .m, .cpp, what have you
const int myInt = 55;
```

But there's got to be a way to put that into `.h` files for use with libraries or other instances where you cannot access the implementation file.

For example, I'm trying to add an `NSString` constant to a `.h` file in an Xcode project like so:

```
static NSString *const myString = @"my_string";
```

however, when I attempt to use `myString`, I get the error

> Initializer element is not a compile-time constant

on `myString`, indicating that it is not being properly instantiated. How does one declare compile-time constants in a C++ or Objecitve-C header file?

Comment: So is this meant to be C or C++? You can initialise globals with run-time expressions in C++, but not in C.

Comment: Good to know that it's not possible for C. Will update tags.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In C++, `const` objects have internal linkage unless explicitly declared `extern`, so there is no problem with putting a definition into a header file such as:

```
const int myInt = 55;
```

With this definition and first declaration, `myInt` can be used as an integer constant expression such as for array bounds and the like.

I can't answer for Objective C.

Comment: @Vorac: This does work in g++ (assuming that you are actually compiling C++ source code). Your edit caused me to waste time re-verifying something that was already correct and it made this answer internally inconsistent. Why would I say "`const` objects have internal linkage" and then and an _explicit_ `static` to the example? If you are not sure about something then comment; don't edit. I have rolled back your edit.